# Sending Lists Using MIME::Lite:TT

Tags: perl, mime

I'm trying to send a list of IPs from a Postgres query via e-mail.

I found MIME::Lite::TT and now have that installed and working.  I'd like to pass 20-30 IPs out in each e-mail in a line feed delimited list.  I could do it by generating a new .txt template for each e-mail I need to send, but that seems inefficient.  I found Template on cpan, and I think the @list part is what I need, but I don't have any idea how to implement it.

Passing $params{ips} = "1.2.3.4\n2.3.4.5\n3.4.5.6\n" didn't work either.

Thanks for your thoughts.

This code sends a single IP successfully:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use MIME::Lite::TT;

# SendTo email id
my $email = 'tester@mydomain.org';

my %params;
$params{ips} = "1.2.3.4";

# create a new MIME Lite based email
my $msg = MIME::Lite::TT->new
(
Subject => "HTML email test",
From    => 'admin@mydomain.org',
To      => $email,
Type    => 'text/html',
Template => 'test.txt',
TmplParams => \%params 
);

$msg->send();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah. Yeah.

Without knowing what your template looks like, it's difficult to come up with a specific suggestion. However, if you set this up as:

```
$params{ips} = [ qw{ 1.2.3.4  2.3.4.5  3.4.5.6 } ];
```

and your template had a region that looked like:

```
[% FOREACH address IN ips %]
[% address %]
[% END %]
```

your problem would be solved, I think. I leave the splitting up of the array into 20–30 element lists as an exercise. :)

Comment: Your answer was exactly what I needed.  Thank you!